# How to pass csv column object through function arg

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I have a lot of duplicate code I would like to clean up. I know the following syntax is not correct, but can you let me know the right way? Lets say I have the following code...

```
Function GetColumnOneValues
{
    Param ($csvFile, $ValuesWithoutNullFile)

    Import-Csv $csvFile | Where-Object {$_.test1ColumnOne} | 
    Export-Csv $ValuesWithoutNullFile -NoTypeInformation -Force
}

Function GetColumnTwoValues
{
    Param ($csvFile, $ValuesWithoutNullFile)

    Import-Csv $csvFile | Where-Object {$_.test2ColumnTwo} | 
    Export-Csv $ValuesWithoutNullFile -NoTypeInformation -Force
}

Function GetColumnThreeValues
{
    Param ($csvFile, $ValuesWithoutNullFile)

    Import-Csv $csvFile | Where-Object {$_.test3ColumnThree} | 
    Export-Csv $ValuesWithoutNullFile -NoTypeInformation -Force
}
```

## ^Notice the duplicate code

```
Function Main
{
    $test1CsvFile = "C:\Scripts\Tests\test1.csv"
    $test1CsvFileResults = "C:\Scripts\Tests\test1Results.csv"
    $test2CsvFile = "C:\Scripts\Tests\test2.csv"
    $test2CsvFileResults = "C:\Scripts\Tests\test2Results.csv"
    $test3CsvFile = "C:\Scripts\Tests\test3.csv"
    $test3CsvFileResults = "C:\Scripts\Tests\test3Results.csv"

    GetColumnOneValues $test1CsvFile $test1CsvFileResults
    GetColumnTwoValues $test2CsvFile $test2CsvFileResults
    GetColumnThreeValues $test3CsvFile $test3CsvFileResults
}

Main
```

## Instead, it should be something like this...

```
Function GetColumnValues
{
    Param ($csvFile, $ValuesWithoutNullFile, $ColumnName)

    Import-Csv $csvFile | Where-Object {$ColumnName} | 
    Export-Csv $ValuesWithoutNullFile -NoTypeInformation -Force
}

Function Main
{
    $test1CsvFile = "C:\Scripts\Tests\test1.csv"
    $test1CsvFileResults = "C:\Scripts\Tests\test1Results.csv"
    $test2CsvFile = "C:\Scripts\Tests\test2.csv"
    $test2CsvFileResults = "C:\Scripts\Tests\test2Results.csv"
    $test3CsvFile = "C:\Scripts\Tests\test3.csv"
    $test3CsvFileResults = "C:\Scripts\Tests\test3Results.csv"

    $column1 = $_.test1ColumnOne
    $column2 = $_.test2ColumnTwo
    $column3 = $_.test3ColumnThree

    GetColumnValues $test1CsvFile $test1CsvFileResults $column1
    GetColumnValues $test2CsvFile $test2CsvFileResults $column2
    GetColumnValues $test3CsvFile $test3CsvFileResults $column3
}

Main
```

However, instead of the function printing out the non-null value, it prints a blank csv file.

## Use these csv Files to test the code...

csvFile1...

```
test1ColumnOne,test1ColumnTwo,test1ColumnThree
qwer,,
,qwer,
,,qwer
```

csvFile2...

```
test2ColumnOne,test2ColumnTwo,test2ColumnThree
asdf,,
,asdf,
,,asdf
```

csvFile3...

```
test3ColumnOne,test3ColumnTwo,test3ColumnThree
zxcv,,
,zxcv,
,,zxcv
```

## Results should be...

test1Results.csv...

```
"test1ColumnOne","test1ColumnTwo","test1ColumnThree"
"qwer","",""
```

test2Results.csv...

```
"test2ColumnOne","test2ColumnTwo","test2ColumnThree"
"","asdf",""
```

test3Results.csv...

```
"test3ColumnOne","test3ColumnTwo","test3ColumnThree"
"","","zxcv"
```

Comment: `(Import-Csv $file).ColumnName`.... that is column object in a sense. Do you want the columns by name or positionally? Do you just want the values or an object column?

Comment: There is no "column object". CSV values are read into the properties of objects, where each object represents one row of the CSV. What is your code supposed to do? Do you want to remove rows with empty fields? Rows with empty fields in a particular column? Extract just one column and remove empty values? "Correct syntax" depends on what the desired result is.

Comment: I updated the question. Let me know if it still isn't making sense. To answer your questions on what my code is supposed to do, i have many scripts utilizing this code for different purposes. But the code duplication is a bit extreme and I wanted to know if there is a way to pass through that `$_.name` as an arg of the function.

Comment: I still don't understand the complexity. Do you need to write it to file? `Import-Csv $file | Select ColumnName | Where {$_.ColumnName}` gets you the column without nulls. Don't even _really_ need a function

Comment: So lets say i have functions for searching for specific text within those columns, but the functions themselves are using the same format and can be merged into 1 function if somehow `$_.columnName` can be passed through the function arg as a variable. For simplicity, i am using the function currently to only look for non-null values, just to show how the code duplicates it. I just wanted it to be easy to read. The purpose of this question is how to pass `$_.columnName` through a function argument.

Comment: Also, forgot and just added `$column#` in the last part of the code.

Comment: I updated the question again to include the csv files for testing the code. There are no syntax errors, but the non-duplicate code prints blank csv files which is different than what the duplicate code prints (which is the results we want).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to clear empty values from a CSV column, retaining a list of non-empty values of that column, I'd do it with a generic function like this:

```
function Remove-EmptyValues {
  Param(
    [Parameter(
      Mandatory=$true,
      Position=0,
      ValueFromPipeline=$true,
      ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true
    )]
    [object[]]$Csv,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=1)]
    [string]$ColumnTitle
  )

  Process {
    $Csv | Select-Object -Expand $ColumnTitle | Where-Object { $_ }
  }
}
```

so it can be used like this

```
$csv = Import-Csv 'C:\testScripts\test.csv'
$noEmpty = Remove-EmptyValues $csv 'column A'
```

or like this:

```
$csv = Import-Csv 'C:\testScripts\test.csv'
$noEmpty = $csv | Remove-EmptyValues -ColumnTitle 'column A'
```

**Edit:** If you want to remove all lines where the value in a particular column is empty, pass input and output filename as well as the name of the column as string parameters:

```
function Remove-EmptyRecords {
  Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0)]
    [string]$Source,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=1)]
    [string]$Destination,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=2)]
    [string]$ColumnTitle
  )

  Import-Csv $Source |
    Where-Object { $_.$ColumnTitle } |
    Export-Csv $Destination -NoType
}

Remove-EmptyRecords test1.csv test1Results.csv test1ColumnOne
Remove-EmptyRecords test2.csv test2Results.csv test2ColumnTwo
Remove-EmptyRecords test3.csv test3Results.csv test3ColumnThree
```

Comment: Hi Ansgar, I just updated the question again... so I really do care much about getting empty values as I do care about somehow passing `$_.columnName` through the function `Param ($_.columnName)`. I have functions that search for strings input by user for every column and I have function that match column values with other column values between csv files. All are duplicated code that could be simplified if there was a way to pass `$_.columnName` through the function argument. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: @FiddleFreak Do you want to pass the *title* of a column, or the *values* of a column?

Comment: Just the title, the values will be the job of the function to figure out.

Comment: See updated answer. That should create the desired output files.

Comment: getting an error 'Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'Path'. Specified method is not supported.+     Export-Csv <<<<  $Destination -NoType'

Comment: oh, i would also like to point out this works as well... Param ($csvFile, $ValuesWithoutNullFile, $ColumnName). I guess you can't assign a `$_.` before you actually import-csv, but after the import-csv `$_.$someStringVariable` works just fine.

Comment: `$_` is an [automatic variable](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx) that holds the current object in a pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you are getting at hear but you `GetColumnValues` so lets build a function with that goal. You have a `columnName` argument. Should add a `-path` one as well.

```
Function Get-ColumnValues{
    Param ($Path, $ColumnName)

    $csvData = Import-Csv $Path
    If($ColumnName -in ($csvData | Get-Member -MemberType "NoteProperty").Name){
        ($csvData).$ColumnName | Where-Object{![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_)}
    } Else {
        Throw "There is no column present called $ColumnName in the file $Path" 
    }
}
```

There is more error prevention that could be included here but simply put this will import a csv and return the values of the requested column assuming it exists.

As an aside the name of your function is misleading if you are exporting the results. You are not only getting them but setting them as well.

Comment: I updated the question, Also note that `if ($_.test1ColumnOne){$_.test1ColumnOne}` will return the value in that column as long as it is not null or an empty string.

Comment: @FiddleFreak Yes. I understand what that code does. `IsNullOrEmpty` is easier to read and understand. If you insisted I would instead do this which does the near the same thing `Where-Object{$_}`

Comment: `[string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace` might be better if you are worried about those as well. I usually just use `Where-Object{$_}` or something similar